# Defining the syntax with constraints

Tags: coq

I want to define the syntax of the time delay in Coq as follows:

```
Inductive tcs : Type :=
| delay : nat -> tcs
| atomic : nat-> tcs.
```

But the natural number 0 is not allowed in the constructor *delay*. I also find using the subset  type to define the syntax. However, the introduction of subset type leads to more complications for defining semantics. Is there an easy way to define such sytax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case, I think the easiest thing to do is to change the interpretation of the number in the `delay` constructor: note that `nat` is isomorphic to `{n : nat | n > 0}` via the successor function.  Therefore, all you have to do is add one to the argument of delay whenever you use it in a `match` expression.  For instance:

```
Definition nat_of_tcs t :=
  match t with
  | delay n => S n
  | atomic n => n
  end.
```

Alternatively, you can replace `nat` by `positive`, a type defined in the standard library to represent numbers greater than 0.

In general, subset types would be the way to go.  You could add a `n != 0` constraint in the type of delay, or define a separate predicate on elements of `tcs` describing when elements are well-formed:

```
Definition well_formed t :=
  match t with
  | delay 0 => false
  | _       => true
  end.

Definition wftcs := { t : tcs | well_formed t = true }.
```

The [Mathematical Components](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/) and related libraries use this pattern pervasively; check the `subType` class in the `eqtype` module, for instance.  In my [extensional structures](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures) library, I use the `subType` class to define a type of finite sets ([here](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures/blob/master/theories/fset.v)) by packaging a list with a proof that the list is sorted.

Comment: How can I construct an instance of `wftcs` such as `atomic n` or `delay n` in the subset type?

Comment: You need to pair `atomic n` (or `delay n`) with a proof `H` that `well_formed (atomic n) = true` holds.  For this, you need to use the `exist` constructor of the `sig` data type that represents subsets: `@exist tcs (fun t => well_formed t = true) (atomic n) H`.

Comment: According to your advce, I define the following lemmas: `Lemma H_atomic_g_is_wftcs : forall (g : nat) (t : tcs), t = atomic g -> well_formed t = true.` and defne the `atomic n` as `Definition wf_atomic_g (g : nat) : wftcs :=
      exist (fun t => well_formed t = true) (atomic g) (H_atomic_g_is_wftcs g (atomic g) eq_refl).` Then I try to define the `delay n`  as `Lemma H_delay_n_is_wftcs : forall (n : nat) (t : tcs), n > 0 -> t = delay n -> well_formed t = true.` However, I get stuck in defining the `wf_delay_n`. How can I handle the `0` in the subset type?

Comment: You cannot handle zero; the point of having the subset type is precisely to make it impossible to use zero with `delay`. To wrap the `delay` constructor, you need to have a proof showing that the number is not zero. As I said before, I think that in this case it is easier to change your `delay` constructor to take in a type such as `positive` as its argument.